# Asymptote with MathJax (specifically Diagrams in MathStack)

Tags: asymptote, mathjax

I want to add asymptote diagrams for my blog, which uses MathJaX. But I can't do it. Any advice on what to do.

Here's an example:

```
import graph; size(15.78cm); 
    real labelscalefactor = 0.5; /* changes label-to-point distance */
    pen dps = linewidth(0.7) + fontsize(10); defaultpen(dps); /* default pen style */ 
    pen dotstyle = black; /* point style */ 
    real xmin = -4.3, xmax = 11.48, ymin = -2.92, ymax = 6.3;  /* image dimensions */
/* draw figures */
draw(circle((3.34,0.98), 3.0345345606863665), linewidth(2.)); 
draw(circle((0.84,-0.74), 3.0345345606863665), linewidth(2.)); 
 /* dots and labels */
dot((3.34,0.98),dotstyle); 
dot((0.84,-0.74),dotstyle); 
clip((xmin,ymin)--(xmin,ymax)--(xmax,ymax)--(xmax,ymin)--cycle); 
 /* end of picture */
```

This gives me this diagram:

[image]

I know we can add asy in LaTeX, because we can do it in Overleaf and *ArtOfProblemSolving* website too.

But can we add asymptote diagrams in Math StackExchange and Blogger, which is MathJaX based?

Comment: Hmm... Is there a reason that the code does not match the image?

Comment: @g.kov  well the code had the first line  /* Geogebra to Asymptote conversion, documentation at artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki go to User:Azjps/geogebra */ which I didn't add ? rest is same ..

Comment: No, this line is just a comment that does not affect the output. 
When I run `asy` on the given code, 
I get two circles and two dots, all in pure black color,
and one circle is clipped, while the given image shows two complete circles 
in some degree of gray and two blue dots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Currently accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/575953/27243)
does not mention that the `Asymptote` is capable also to produce
output in `png`, `svg` and (for interactive 3D `html`) `webgl` format.

Unfortunately, the image uploading system of `Math.SE`
does not allow to upload `svg` images, but
at least you can avoid screen shots by
creating the images in `png` format with

```
asy -f png -render=4  <asy-file>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that mathjax is not actually LaTeX but a reimplementation of a subset of LaTeX (just the math) in JavaScript. asymptote is also not LaTeX but is a separate program which outputs eps or pdf files. As such it's several steps away from mathjax.

Your best bet for using asymptote diagrams in your blog is to generate the diagrams and then take screenshots and import the screenshots as images to the blog (or Math.SE).

Comment: yeah screen shots works!